# mysql in bash with variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mysql

How can i parse a variable in a mysql update statement in a bash script?

i have this but its not going to work

```
mysql -h HOST -u USERNAME -pUGUESIT -D DATABASE -bse "DELETE FROM table WHERE Position='" . $4 ."'; DELETE FROM table WHERE Instance='" . $4 . "';"
```

ofcourse username and pass etc are correct but not for public. The question is how I can use the $4 in the statement...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
"DELETE FROM table WHERE Position='$4'; DELETE FROM table WHERE Instance='$4';"
```

Comment: ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1: DELETE command denied to user 'USER'@'IP' for table 'table'

im sure i got the rights becouse without $1 and with like 1 it will delete Instance 1

Comment: Thnx it works now. found the problem.
need to do databasename.table in the query